# qgraphicsitem paint function not called

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem

I inherit `Qgraphicsitem`, my `boundingrect` function is called when i add it to scene, but `paint` function never called, my class declaration is:

```
class advertisementObject:public QGraphicsItem
{
public:
    advertisementObject(QGraphicsItem *parents = 0);

    QRectF boundingRect()const;
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget);
};
```

here is where I add it to scene:

viewer->getUi()->viewportu->scene()->addItem(advertisementEditor);
when i add it to scene, boundingrect is calling but paint function never called. my class declaration is :

```
    advertisementObject::advertisementObject(QGraphicsItem *parents)
        :QGraphicsItem(parents)
    {
     }
QRectF advertisementObject::boundingRect() const
{
    return QRectF(-1, -1, 1500, 1500);
}

void advertisementObject::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    QRectF temp(0, 0, 1500, 1500);
    painter->fillRect(temp, Qt::white);
}
```

Comment: How do you know that it's not called?

Comment: have you tried`setParentItem(this)` before adding item?

Comment: @thuga : I add break point in my function, but i never reach it.

Comment: @Idgormen : this object is called inside a mainwindow object and doesn't have parent item.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in the code you posted. Can you show the method where you create the `advertisementEditor` object and add it to the scene?